# Accessing gnu make options

Tags: makefile, conditional-statements, arguments

I'd like to make part of a makefile's execution conditional on whether -B was used when calling make (ie, full recompilation).

Is there a way to access this argument from within MAKE?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the `MAKEFLAGS` variable. The following code fragment runs if -B was passed as an argument.

```
ifeq (B,$(MAKEFLAGS))
    @echo Do something
endif
```

Comment: That's not a great way to do it as it will be false if you provide any other options in addition to `-B`.  Try something like: `ifeq ($(word 1,$(MAKEFLAGS)),$(subst B,-,$(word 1,$(MAKEFLAGS)))) ...used -B...`